# Possible to pass a ScalaTags bundle to a function for cross-backend code?

Tags: scalatags

I have a project with a dozen classes that need to represent their private state as HTML.  Each has a `toHTML` function.  I'd like to pass that function a ScalaTags bundle so it can be rendered as either text (to print to a file) or as a DOM element for display directly in a browser.

Here's my attempt:

```scala
case class MyClass(...) extends ... {

  // Render private state as HTML, either Text or DOM.
  override def toHTML[Builder, Output <: FragT, FragT](
      bundle: scalatags.generic.Bundle[Builder, Output, FragT]
  ): TypedTag[Builder, Output, FragT] = {
    import bundle.all._

    li("Here is a list element")
  }
}
```

Even this simple example reports a compile-time error:

```
MyClass.scala:43:8: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : String("Here is a list element")
[error]  required: scalatags.generic.Modifier[Builder]
[error]     li("Here is a list element")
[error]        ^
```

I've tried importing `bundle.generic.implicits._` but it doesn't help and the compiler reports it as unused.

I'm aware that this is different from what the [documentation](https://com-lihaoyi.github.io/scalatags/#Cross-backendCode) shows in that I'm attempting to pass the bundle to the function rather than as a class parameter.  I'd prefer to pass it to the function because `toHTML` is the only thing in a fairly complex class that has anything to do with HTML.  I'd rather not clutter the entire class with stuff that only one function needs.

I've considered moving all the `toHTML` code from each of the dozen classes into a single class (using pattern matching to distinguish the cases).  That would more closely match the documentation but means that I need to make a bunch of private state more visible.  I'd rather not.

Any suggestions for how to get the above code to work?  Is it a trivial error on my part or something that fundamentally can't work?